# ISO: UIDatePicker control

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, datepicker

In my project, I have a button and when I push this button I should open a datapicker; how can I do? Have I create an other UIViewController with delegate method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a really good example w/ some sample code.  This one also adds a bit of animation and generally gives a good user experience:

[Bottom pop-up UIPicker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441651/bottom-pop-up-uipicker)